# Flag count on Area 51

Tags: feature-request, area-51, flags

Why is there not a flag count for Area 51? As a user that likes to help out on SO as much as possible, I enjoy to see my flag count on the different sites, so that I can see what I need to improve on, and so that I can also see how accurate I am at flagging questions/answers. So can the flag count be implemented on Area 51, like it is on every other Stack Exchange site?